# Win 10 network connection order not saving

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have both a Ethernet and USB WiFi dongle connection going into my desktop, and the Ethernet is a much better connection. I want my computer to only connect to WiFi when Ethernet is not working(Ethernet is coming from a powerline so it is not the most stable).

When I go into Network and Sharing Center and change the advanced settings to make Ethernet the top of the Connections List, my connection does not switch to Ethernet. When I go back into the Connections List it shows WiFi at the top again.

Why is this happening, and is there a better way to switch between Ethernet and Wifi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually set Metric for network interfaces. Lower Metric means higher priority. So, Metric for your USB network adapter should be set higher then for Ethernet adapter.

How to set Metric:

1. Go to the properties of your network adapter.
2. Go to the properties of `Internet Protocol Version 4` (I assume IP version 4 is used).

[image: Network adapter properties]

3. Click `Advanced`.

[image: Internet Protocol Version 4 properties]

4. At the bottom of the `Advanced TCP/IP settings` window remove the checkmark `Automatic metric` and manually assign a number.

[image: Advanced TCP/IP settings]

You can list current Metric settings by executing command `netstat -rn`. With option `-r` netstat will list routing table which includes Metric settings.